# _reactNavigation.NavigationActions.push is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am getting an error
`_reactNavigation.NavigationActions.push is not a function`
when trying to navigate to same route.
I am applying the accepted solution from below link
[React-Navigation go to same route with different params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050850/react-navigation-go-to-same-route-with-different-params/51015196#51015196)