# React native navigation - too many screens in stack

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Hi I am new to React native and React native navigation. I am using react navigation screen to show details about users. I have around 100 different users. I am navigating to the next user by using `push` instead of `navigate` as I have to pass different props (same screen, different parameters).

```
navigation.push('UserDetails', {id: id + 1})
```

This method is mentioned in the documentation and this thread:

[React-Navigation go to same route with different params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050850/react-navigation-go-to-same-route-with-different-params)

However, as there are a lot of users, this ends up creating a lot of screens on the stack and creates performance issues and crashes. Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Please explain it a little bit more. As for my understanding, you have 1 screen where users are listed. And clicking on any User you are showing that user details. If yes then use navigation.navigate('UserDetails',{id}). And in "UserDetails" call api for that user to get details of that user

Comment: Yes your understanding is correct. But as I mentioned, I have around 100 students. I navigate to the next student with a button in UserDetails page. This will take me to same page with different props.

Home -> UserDetails(id) -> UserDetails(id+1) -> UserDetails(id+2)...

Comment: I tried using `navigate`, but it does not update the page with the new props. So I am forced to use `push`. Is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use navigation for this purpose.
You need to triger screen update according to user id (at screen state or Redux Store).