# Allow cycle and same screen names with nested stack navigator

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a complex app where there are 5 pages (Bottom Tab Navigator) and multiple screens (Native Stack Navigator). The multiple screens are supposed to open in the 5 pages. I wish to use the same screen names in the 5 pages and multiple screens for consistency purposes and I have the requirement of having cycles of these screens being opened. I'm getting lots of warnings regarding cycling nested screens and screens with the same names such as:

- `Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.`
- Screens with same name warning:

  ```
  Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check:
  Home -> PROVIDER_PAGE -> PRODUCT_PAGE -> PROVIDER_PAGE -> PRODUCT_PAGE
  This can cause confusing behavior during navigation. Consider using unique names for each screen instead.
  ```

How can I achieve this in the clean way and ignore these warnings?

[Sample Project Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@amandeep3/test)

Comment: Seems like You are importing something from "file A" into "file B", then importing something again from "file B" into "file A"

Comment: Yes, I need to achieve this. How can I do it in a clean way? This behaviour can be found in other apps such as Instagram.

Comment: could you please create a Minimal example .? would be easier to resolve.

Comment: I believe your question may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47050850/react-navigation-go-to-same-route-with-different-params

Comment: @AmanDeep, I have created and provided the link in the question of my sample Snack on Expo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your Tab and Stack navigators structure like this to achieve your requirement,

- Tab Navigator

  - Home Stack

    1. Home Screen
    2. Product screen
    3. Provider Screen
  - Explore Stack

    1. Explore Screen
    2. Product Screen
    3. Provider Screen

I have added this change in Home Tab Navigator of your snack, you may check it [here](https://snack.expo.dev/gk6u4TV59).

Mainly I have removed the Stack Navigator from each Product and Provider screen, and
added a **title** parameter in `navigation.push` .

Comment: Thanks for the help but how can I check which instance of Screen is currently open? Or how can I detect when the screen becomes active again after the pushed screen gets closed? I have some logic that requires this information.

Comment: You can use [useFocusEffect](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-focus-effect/) or other navigation events for that.